# How to write unit separator into XML 1.0?

Tags: xml, msxml, separator

I have "unit separator" 0x1F stored in database.

All I wanted is to use MSXML6.dll to export the unit separator to XML 1.0 format.

Here are the pains I've got:

1. Write 0x1F into XML file directly, error message, the attribute ended up with empty string.
2. Replace with HTML Entity "& # x 1 F;", then write into XML file, it turned out to be: "& a m p ; # x 1 F;", which is disappointing.
3. If I manually change XML file to replace "& a m p ; # x 1 F ;" to "& # x 1 F ;", the XML parser fail with exception "Invalid Unicode Character".

**The Question:**
So, if I can not use XML 1.1, what's the best solution to write "unit separator" into XML file and importable?

Note: One possible solution is to replace "unit separator" with some STRANGE string like "*$*". But is this a good name at all?
      What's your opinion if I use "0x1F" or "#x1F" or "#x1F;" instead of "&#x1F"? Which is better or any better candidates?

---

**Summary:**

Let's make an analogy: Let's think about how the compiler works, there are two phases: "Pre-compile" and "Compile".

For XML File Generation, it acts like the "Compile" phase. E.g. convert "<" to "& l t ;"

However, the Unit Separator is not supported by XML 1.0, so the "Compile" phase will not convert it to HTML Entity "& # x 1 F ;"

So we have to seek solution in the "Pre-Compile" phase, which is our own application's responsibility.

When writing:

```
Option1: <unit>aaa</unit><unit>bbb</unit>
Option2: simply use "_x241F_" to replace "\37" in the string if "_x241F_" is not conflicting with any existing token in the string.
```

When reading:

```
According to Option1: Load the elements, catenate to a single string with "\37" as separator.
According to Option2: simply use "\37" to replace "_x241F_".
```

I've also found out that MSXML (even the highest version MSXML6.dll) will not load XML 1.1 .

So if we are unfortunately using MSXML, we have to write our own "Pre-Compile" code to handle the Unicode characters before feeding the "Compile" phase.

Note: I borrowed the idea of "_ x 2 4 1F _" from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx).
Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: No current experience with MSXML, but I am [amazed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). If the char 0x1F, and `&#31;` or `&#x001F;` do not work, try `<[CDATA[... char 0x1F ...]]>`.

Comment: So you are suggesting "<![CDATA[&#x1F;]]>"? I will give a try. Thanks

Comment: Hi Joop, Since the unit separator is in a value of an attribute (appears in quotes), it ended up in the XML file to be "&lt;![CDATA[&amp;#x1F;]]&gt;"

Comment: What's you opinion if I use "0x1F" or "#x1F" or "#x1F;" instead of "&#x1F"? Which is better or any better candidates?

Comment: Sorry a CDATA does not work inside an attribute. Most logically should be the control character US with code 0x1F aka 31. Entity `&#31;` seems the simplest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe appending an internal DTD to the XML file might work for you?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [<!ENTITY 0x1F "&#x1F;">]>
<root>
  <Units>Unit1&0x1F;Unit2</Units>
</root>
```

Comment: That's a good idea, which I don't know before.  However, in my project, I can not add the internal DTD and I can not expect where the XML file is coming from (so I should expect the XML file would not have this DTD)

Comment: Marked as answer. However, I'm not adopting this method in my project. Refer to "Summary" section...

Comment: @milesma Imo you shouldn't accept an answer that didn't help you, even if it's a great idea